# Java based Word mapping (semantic) application

Tags: java, semantics, semantic-web, text-mining, wordnet

I want to develop an Java based application to map synonyms to a unique code or a word. For example in medical terms, the word  `heart attack`  or  `cardiac arrest` etc. means the same thing. So I want to build a database ( need no be an RDBMS) to store such mappings. Such mappings have to be added/ modified or deleted later on.

The primary objective is to develop an application to map semantically together entities.

My input will be like a two or three word phrase and it will be mapped to a standard code. example **heart attack** and **cardiac arrest** mapped to a disease code **HA50122445**.  Tomorrow, if I find a new phrase  say **myo cardiac inflammation**, I want to map it to the code **HA50122445**

I looked at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/index.html), but it is for text mining , primarity based on search keywords. My requirements is kind of similar to [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/). Is the Wordnet database editable or modifiable ? My research says no. Is it right ?

It would be really helpful, if you could guide me. Thank you

Comment: Are you interested in how to develop an ontology of diseases, where different names of the same condition map to the same value, or in how one can store such an ontology.

Comment: Yea, Ontology would have been a choice if I were considering the conditions and using the conditions predicting which is the disease. Here the idea is to map reported cause of deaths to standard codes. So you start with a few and slowly grow the database. It is kind of a synonym mapping or thesauri thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out [UMLS metathesaurus](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/pubs/factsheets/umlsmeta.html) and [MetaMap](http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/). The former is "a large, multi-purpose, and multi-lingual thesaurus that contains millions of biomedical and health related concepts". That must have some identifiers in it. You can base your "database" on that, because building it yourself over time is going to be extremely laborious. The latter is a natural language processing toolkit which scans text, discovers medical concepts and maps them to entries in the UMLS thesaurus.

Disclaimer: I have not used either of these resources. My team has built similar resources for a client, but there are not freely available, thus my not recommending them.

Comment: Totally, I was looking for something like this.  Can we amend or build on top of the UMLS metathesaurus ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Brat Rapid Annotation Tool

http://brat.nlplab.org/index.html

It lets you annotate a document, indicate that two different phrases are in fact the same thing, and point those entities to a canonical reference.

It stores the data in flat files. You could even use Stanford's CoreNLP to learn variants (like heart-attack or "myocardial infarction") and recognize them as the same thing.

Wordnet is downloadable and you can always add new info to your downloaded version.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap`, synonymous as keys to your one "HA501225.." object.

```
Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put("Heart Attack", "HA50..");
lookup.put("cardiac arrest", "HA50..");

//lookup is now simple -
lookup.get("Heart Attack") // gives us HA5012..
```

Simple starting solution, once you run into problems then optimise from there once you encounter scaling issues or what have you. You could perhaps look into Redis, or another key value database which can give you these mappings.

Answer (score -2):

An RDBMS is the best solution for that. Simply choose one. Embedded example: HSQLDB. But any mysql or postgre should fit.

Comment: I just looked up wordnet and it seems to me, that wordnet is rather an application than a database, that has allready quite a lot of data in it's included database. Might be an RDBMS under the hood. Might not. It's definitely not what you're searching for. Though it's concepts might be interesting for you.